# How to pass showDatePicker data to another screen through widget for update

Tags: flutter, datepicker, widget

I still new in learning flutter and I trying to pass the _selectedDate that select from showDatePicker to another page by widget. But I don't know how to pass it, anyone know how to display the value that pass to another page as default value. The date is passing to update page through Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute()) and the _selectedDate defination is same as update page.

**#HomePage that passing data**

```
   Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UpdatingTaskPage(
                              id: _task.id!,
                              title: _task.title!,
                              note: _task.note!,
                              isCompleted: false,
                              date: _task.date!,
                              startTime: _task.startTime!,
                              endTime: _task.endTime!,
                              color: _task.color!,
                              remind: _task.remind!,
                              repeat: _task.repeat!,
                            ),                                   
                          ),
                        );
```

**#Updating Page**

```
class UpdatingTaskPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String date;

  const UpdatingTaskPage(
      {super.key,
      required this.date,
});

  @override
  State<UpdatingTaskPage> createState() => _UpdatingTaskPageState();
}

class _UpdatingTaskPageState extends State<UpdatingTaskPage> {
  static TaskController controller = Get.put(TaskController());
  final task = controller.tasks.length;

  late DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();

// set the initial state to the existing value
  @override
  void initState() {
    _startTime = widget.startTime;
    _endTime = widget.endTime;
    _selectedRemind = widget.remind;
    _selectedRepeat = widget.repeat;
    _selectedColor = widget.color;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    titleController.text = widget.title;
    noteController.text = widget.note;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Update task!"),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // this icon button is for the user to signout
                AuthController.instance.logout();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.logout_rounded))
        ],
      ),
      body:
          Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [        
              //Date
              InputField(
                title: 'Date',
                hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => _getDateFromUser(),
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.calendar_today_outlined,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),         
      );
  }



  _getDateFromUser() async {
    DateTime? _pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    );
    if (_pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = _pickedDate;
      });
    } else {
      print('picked date empty !');
    }
  }
}
```

[image: date always current date instead of pass date that selected]
[image: error when changing or set state _selectedDate = widget.date]

Comment: where do you want to pass the data from the showDatePicker ? back to the homepage ?

Comment: I want to pass the data from home page to the updating page. In my updating page, the default value is _selectedDate = DateTime.now() so which means the default value will always be the current date instead of the pass date that stored in firebase (refer to the image 1), I unable to change _selectedDate = widget.date or set the state that pass from homepage else it will given error 
═ Exception caught by widgets library ═════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast
(refer to image 2)

Comment: because you passing the String type as Date did you try to change the type as DateTime ?

Comment: you means change String Date to DateTime? I have change it still given the same error. Maybe you can explain more details?